# How to avoid double gap between the columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**bootstrap 5.0.0-beta1**

```
              <!doctype html>
              <html lang="en">
                <head>
                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
                  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
                </head>
              <body>
              <div style="background:blue;" class="container">
                  <div class="row gx-5">
                      <div style="background:red; background-clip: content-box;" class="col-12 col-lg-8">Red</div>
                      <div style="background:green; background-clip: content-box;" class="col-12 col-lg-4">Green</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              </body>
              </html>
```

https://codepen.io/Nonverbis/pen/jOVOYGE

Could you tell me how to avoid double gap between the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For results similar to this:**
[image]

Use

```css
<div class="row">...</div>
```

i.e. remove `gx-5` from the class.

**For results similar to this:**
[image]

Use

```css
<div class="row gx-0">...</div>
```

i.e. use `gx-0` in the class